# Using preg_replace() for template engines

Tags: php, preg-replace

As i am trying to learn about basic template engines, i was trying out different codes. And i noticed this issue that i don't understand.
i am new, so any help would be appreciated.

Template.php :

```
class Template {

public function render ($template_name) {
    $path = $template_name . '.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $contents = file_get_contents($path);


        $contents = preg_replace('/\{\% for (.+) = (\d+) to (\d+) \%\}/', '<?php for ($$1 = $2; $$1 < $3; $$1++): ?>', $contents);
        $contents = preg_replace('/\{\% (.+) \%\}/', '<?php echo $$1; ?>', $contents);
        $contents = preg_replace('/\{\% endfor \%\}/', '<?php endfor ?>', $contents);

        eval(' ?>' . $contents . '<?php ');
    }else{
        exit ('<h1> Template Eror</h1>');
    }
}
}
?>
```

test.php :

```
    {% for i = 0 to 10 %}
        <b> i = {% i %}  </b><br>
    {% endfor %}
```

index.php :

```
include 'Template.php';

$template = new Template;

$template->render('myTemplate');
```

the output is:

```
i = 0 
i = 1 
i = 2 
i = 3 
i = 4 
i = 5 
i = 6 
i = 7 
i = 8 
i = 9
```

But in Template.php if `$contents = preg_replace('/\{\% (.+) \%\}/', '<?php echo $$1; ?>', $contents);` is placed before either 'for' 'endfor' lines the output shows :

```
This page isn’t working 
127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: If you want to create a very basic template engine, then I would just handle the layouts and use ordinary PHP in the templates. If you want to create your own syntax, it won't be very basic, since there will pop up a multitude of situations and combinations you haven't thought about. You would need to add support for functions as well (like escaping the output to protect against XSS etc).

Comment: It also looks like all you're doing is more or less just replacing `<?php` and `?>` with `{%` and `%}`.

Comment: It also looks like all you're doing is more or less just replacing <?php and ?> with {% and %}-i get that. But i don't understand why the replacing is not working.what could change for replacing the last 2 lines/

Comment: Please edit your question to include some example content for `$contents` and explain in detail what _"doesn't work"_ mean. Add what actually happens in the two different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second lines:

```
$contents = preg_replace('/\{\% (.+) \%\}/', '<?php echo $$1; ?>', $contents);
```

replaces every  `{% endfor %}` so the third line never match any `{% endfor %}` that's why you have to exchange those two lines.